# How to write search query in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, search

I was trying to write a search query in hibernate. I took help from open-meeting source code. 
So my query:

```
public User getAllUser(String search) {
    String[] searchItems = search.split(" ");
    try {
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM  USER u " + "WHERE u.deleted = 1 ";
        sqlQuery += "AND ( ";
        for (int i = 0; i < searchItems.length; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                sqlQuery += " OR ";
            }
            sqlQuery += "( " + "lower(u.last_name) LIKE '"
                    + StringUtils.lowerCase("%" + searchItems[i] + "%")
                    + "' " + "OR lower(u.first_name) LIKE '"
                    + StringUtils.lowerCase("%" + searchItems[i] + "%")
                    + "' " + "OR lower(u.username) LIKE '"
                    + StringUtils.lowerCase("%" + searchItems[i] + "%")
                    + "' " + ") ";
        }
        sqlQuery += " )";

        log.debug("sqlQuery : " + sqlQuery);
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                sqlQuery);

        return (User) query.list().get(0);

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

It says there is an unexpected token, I but I didn't find where it is.

**So I have two questions:**

1. how to make it functional.
2. how to write search query using Criteria and Projection/Restrictions in hibernate

Comment: How about reading the documentation and the javadoc? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria

Comment: Are you getting this error each time regardless, or is it occuring with specific search strings? Can you give an example of the SQL output that is causing the error.

Comment: Hey @perissf I didn't get it...

Comment: hey @Digbyswift i solve it. I solved it using createSqlQuery method. I was looking how to convert it using Criteria ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a hibernate query. It is a native SQl. You should use createSQLQuery as below

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSqlQuery(
                sqlQuery);
```

Refer [this](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/selectclause.shtml) for select using hibernate.

Also, I would suggest you to go with [Criterias](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)

Answer (score 3):

You  can use:

```
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("" +
            "select * from OdontogramaDiagnosticoModel where odontologia = :idOdontologia");
    query.setParameter("idOdontologia", "102");
    return query.list();
```

There's 2 things demonstrated here that you should take note of:

- How to execute a custom query
- How to parameterize your query ([for security reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection))

Another example:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(OdontologiaDiagnostico.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("diagnosticosClinicos", "test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This all looks very complex and untidy. Have you considered using Hibernate Search instead? It was designed to make queries like this straightforward.

Comment: i was thinking to use hibernate search, but hibernate search is design for full-text search, so far I know.. right now I dont need full text search.

Comment: That's fair. I was just commenting that what you're trying to do in your code is something which Hibernate Search is designed for.